# sub Floating Action Buttons does not return to the main floating action button

Tags: android, floating-action-button

whenever i click my floating action button, another two floating action buttons appear, one to open the camera the other to upload a picture, the problem is when i choose on of the sub action buttons and go to the next activity, everything works fine but when i return to the main page of the floating action button, the two sub button still outside the main floating button

i have to re-open the app to fix it,

here is my code

```
private void setupFloatingActionMenu(Context context) {
        ImageView imgv = new ImageView(context); // Create an icon
        imgv.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

        FloatingActionButton actionButton = new FloatingActionButton.Builder((Activity) context)
                .setContentView(imgv)

                .build();
        ImageView capture = new ImageView(context);
        capture.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);


        ImageView upload = new ImageView(context);
        upload.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

        SubActionButton.Builder itemBuilder = new SubActionButton.Builder((Activity) context);

        SubActionButton buttonSortCap = itemBuilder.setContentView(capture).build();
        SubActionButton buttonSortUpd = itemBuilder.setContentView(upload).build();

        FloatingActionMenu actionMenu = new FloatingActionMenu.Builder((Activity) context)
                .addSubActionView(buttonSortCap)
                .addSubActionView(buttonSortUpd)
                .setRadius(150)
                .enableAnimations()
                .attachTo(imgv)
                .build();
        buttonSortCap.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                captureImage();
            }
        });
        buttonSortUpd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, ""), PICK_IMAGE);
            }
        });

    }
```